# How to disable ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'" in docker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, docker, nginx

I am building a dockerized (version 20.10.11) application with `php7`,`nginx(1.21)` images. I am adding `colorbox` `jquery` library for youtube popup.

Upon clicking youtube thumbnail link popup appears but videos not playing. In `console` errors appears like

> Refused to frame 'http://myapp.docker.localhost:8000/' because an
> ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "frame-ancestors 'none'".

but it works without any issues in `xampp`,`wamp` etc.

How can I disable this restriction in `docker`?

I am pretty new to `docker` and `nginx`.